# Rails/React app - Capybara-Selenium::WebDriver::Error is not clickable at point, Other element would receive the click:

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

Gem file below:

```html
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara-selenium'
  gem "chromedriver-helper"
end
```

I'm testing rails app with react view. The test is going through the motions but when it comes to clicking on the button it clicks somewhere else.

rails_helper.rb

```html
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'selenium/webdriver'
require 'chromedriver/helper'


Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5


Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!

end
```

test_spec.rb

```html
require 'rails_helper'


feature "Select a Work Station" do
  scenario "User should select a embedding work station" , js: true do

    # 1- Go to login screen and authenticate
   visit "http://localhost:3001"
  fill_in('Email', :with => 'xxx')
  fill_in('Password', :with => 'xxxx')
  click_button("Submit")
    # save_and_open_screenshot

    # 2- Select an account
    find('tr[accountname="Clinical Pathology Laboratories"]').click
    # save_and_open_screenshot

    # 3- Use default location
  click_button("Save")
    # save_and_open_screenshot

    # 4- Click on the Embedding button
    find('img[alt="Embedding"]').click

    # 5- Start Session
    find('#work_station_id').find('option', text: "Embedding #1").select_option

    # ------------ clicking action ------
    # page.driver.browser.action.move_to(find('button', text: "Start Session")).move_by(0, 5)
    # expect(page).to have_select('#work_station_id')
    # select 'Embedding #1', :from => '#work_station_id'
    # page.driver.browser.mouse.move_to(find('button', text: "Start Session"), 0, 5)
    # find('button[class="btn btn-success"]').click
    # page.click_link_or_button('Start Session')
    # click_button("Start Session")
  end
end
```

The problem starts # ------------ clicking action ------ and below where I try to click on the button, but where I expect it to move me forward to the next page.I've tried to click on 'Start Session' button many differnt ways. Instead, I get that button is not clickable at point ect...

```html
 Failure/Error: page.click_link_or_button('Start Session')
     
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       unknown error: Element <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#undefined">...</button> is not clickable at point (628, 358). Other element would receive the click: <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">...</div>
         (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that that you have another element (<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">...</div>) over the button you're trying to click.  You'll need to figure out why it's there and then perform any actions necessary to make the button available.  This may include, scrolling the page, making the screen size bigger so things don't overlap, closing the offending element (if it's a modal, etc).

Additionally you're using selenium action methods, but passing Capybara elements to them, and not actually performing the actions.

If you want to call those methods you need to call `native` on the Capybara elements to get the selenium native element reference and call perform on the end of your action chain to actually make it do something.

```
page.driver.browser.action.move_to(find('button', text: "Start Session").native).move_by(0, 5).perform
```